# Is there any solution except integration by parts for $\int_0^\infty x^2 e^{-x} \sin(\alpha x) dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-differential-equations, self-learning

I want to calculate the Fourier sine integral and the Fourier cosine integral of the function $f(x)=x^2e^{-x}$. So I have to calculate:
$$
\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-x}\sin(\alpha x)dx \qquad , \qquad \int_0^\infty x^2e^{-x}\cos(\alpha x)dx
$$

The integration by parts method is really complex for these two integrals! 
Is there any better solution to calculate them?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^2 e^{-(1-i\alpha)x}\,dx=\frac{1}{(1-i\alpha)^3}\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^2 e^{-x}\,dx =\frac{2}{(1-i\alpha)^3}=\frac{2}{(1+\alpha^2)^3}(1+i\alpha)^3 $$
then you may just consider the real or imaginary parts of both sides to get:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}x^2 e^{-x}\cos(\alpha x)\,dx = \frac{2-6\alpha^2}{(1+\alpha^2)^3},\qquad \int_{0}^{+\infty}x^2 e^{-x}\sin(\alpha x)\,dx = \frac{6\alpha-2\alpha^3}{(1+\alpha^2)^3}.$$

Comment: A small nitpick, as $(1-i\alpha)x\mapsto x$, $+\infty\not\mapsto+\infty$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: all right, the change of variable $x\mapsto\frac{x}{1-i\alpha}$ change the upper bound $+\infty$ into $\frac{+infty}{1-i\alpha}$, but by applying the ML Lemma the integral $\int_{M}^{\frac{M}{1-i\alpha}}$ converges to zero so we are allowed to leave $+\infty$ as endpoint of the integration range, after the substitution.

Answer (score 5):

One might consider the following integral:

$$f(\alpha)=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\sin(\alpha x)~\mathrm dx$$

This can be solved using Euler's formula:

$$\begin{align}f(\alpha)&=\Im\int_0^\infty e^{(i\alpha-1)x}~\mathrm dx\\&=\Im\left[\frac{e^{(i\alpha-1)x}}{i\alpha-1}\right]_0^\infty\\&=\Im\left[\frac1{1-i\alpha}\right]\end{align}$$

Likewise, from the integral representation:

$$f''(\alpha)=-\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-x}\sin(\alpha x)~\mathrm dx$$

And from the closed form:

$$f''(\alpha)=\Im\left[\frac{-2}{(i\alpha-1)^3}\right]=\Im\left[\frac{2(i\alpha+1)^3}{(\alpha^2+1)^3}\right]=\frac{2\alpha^3-6\alpha}{(\alpha^2+1)^3}$$

Likewise,

$$\begin{align}g(\alpha)&=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\cos(\alpha x)~\mathrm dx\\&=\Re\int_0^\infty e^{(i\alpha-1)x}~\mathrm dx\\&=\Re\left[\frac1{1-i\alpha}\right]\\\implies f''(\alpha)&=\Re\left[\frac{2(i\alpha+1)^3}{(\alpha^2+1)^3}\right]=\frac{2-6\alpha^2}{(\alpha^2+1)^3}\end{align}$$

$$f''(\alpha)=-\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-x}\cos(\alpha x)~\mathrm dx$$

Answer (score 0):

Laplace transform

$\mathcal{L}\{x^2\sin\alpha x\}(s)=-\dfrac{2 a \left(a^2-3 s^2\right)}{\left(a^2+s^2\right)^3}$

your integral is

$\mathcal{L}\{x^2\sin\alpha x\}(1)=-\dfrac{2 a \left(a^2-3\right)}{\left(a^2+1\right)^3}$

For cosine is

$\mathcal{L}\{x^2\cos\alpha x\}(1)=\dfrac{2 \left(1-3 a^2\right)}{\left(a^2+1\right)^3}$

Comment: Well, (it is just my opinion that) Laplace transform does not address the OP's need, since approaches to get the result also involve integration by part.

Comment: @BAI I just looked on tables :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use complex numbers, you'll find $\int_0^\infty e^{-\beta x}\cos\alpha x$ and its sine counterpart are relatively easy by parts. Then just apply $\partial_\beta^2$ and set $\beta=1$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, for any real numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta>0$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty} x^\beta e^{-x} \sin (\alpha x) d x 
& =\Im \int_0^{\infty} x^\beta e^{-x} e^{\alpha x i} d x \\
& = \Im \int_0^{\infty} x^\beta e^{-(1-\alpha i) x} d x \\
& = \Im\left[\frac{\Gamma(\beta+1)}{(1-\alpha i)^{\beta+1}}\right] \\
& =\Gamma(\beta+1) \Im \left[ \frac{(1+\alpha i)^{\beta+1}}{\left(1+\alpha^2\right)^{\beta+1}} \right]\\
& =\frac{\Gamma(\beta+1)}{\left(1+\alpha^2\right)^{\beta+1}} \Im\left[(1+\alpha i)^{\beta+1}\right] \\
&
\end{aligned}
As a bonus,
$$\int_0^{\infty} x^\beta e^{-x} \cos (\alpha x) d x= \frac{\Gamma(\beta+1)}{\left(1+\alpha^2\right)^{\beta+1}} \Re\left[(1+\alpha i)^{\beta+1}\right] \tag*{} $$
In particular, $\beta=2$,
$$\int_0^{\infty} x^2 e^{-x} \sin (\alpha x) d x= \frac{\Gamma(3)}{\left(1+\alpha^2\right)^{3}} \Im\left[(1+\alpha i)^{3}\right]= \frac{6 \alpha-2 \alpha^3}{\left(1+\alpha^2\right)^3}
$$
$$\int_0^{\infty} x^2e^{-x} \cos (\alpha x) d x = \frac{2-6 \alpha^2}{\left(1+\alpha^2\right)^3}
$$